How to solve TomEE start "WARNING: You didn't specify org.apache.batchee.jmx.application and JMX is already registered, skipping"?
JSF version:
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Server version:
tomee-plume-10.0.0-M2
Log message:
10月 09, 2024 9:31:06 上午 org.apache.batchee.container.services.ServicesManager init
WARNING: You didn't specify org.apache.batchee.jmx.application and JMX is already registered, skipping

I already found: Explaining TomEE start error "You didn't specify org.apache.batchee.jmx.application and JMX is already registered, skipping"
But he didn't say where to set the setting openejb.batchee.integration.skip=true, org.apache.batchee.jmx=false completely.
The official documentation: https://geronimo.apache.org/batchee/configuration.html
just say batchee.properties can configure the JBatch container. It will look up in the classloader (advise: put it in container loader).
He neither say where to setting clearly.
I tried to setting:
1. /src/main/resources/batchee.properties it dosen't work, still have the warning message.
2. /src/main/webapp/META-INF/batchee.properties it dosen't work, still have the warning message.
3. /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>openejb.batchee.integration.skip</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.batchee.jmx</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

it dosen't work, still have the warning message.
4.1. /Servers/tomee-plume-10.0.0-M2 at localhost-config/context.xml (in eclipse)
10月 09, 2024 10:01:53 上午 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement WARNING: No rules found matching [Context/context-param/param-name]
4.2./Servers/tomee-plume-10.0.0-M2 at localhost-config/server.xml (in eclipse)
10月 09, 2024 10:10:54 上午 java.lang.reflect.Method invoke WARNING: No rules found matching [Server/Service/Engine/Host/context-param/param-name]
4.3. /Servers/tomee-plume-10.0.0-M2 at localhost-config/web.xml (in eclipse)
it dosen't work, still have the warning message.
5. \apache-tomee-plume-10.0.0-M2\conf\web.xml
it dosen't work, still have the warning message.
Please tell me how to solve the warning clearly, please.
Excuse me, and thank you.

You can add the propery to the system.properties in /conf of TomEE
